# How to use an if statement that accounts for an int in a singular sense

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm new to coding and C#; So, my apologies for the generic question.

I've created a basic random number guessing game; However, when I try to put if statements around the correct answers, it appears to fail.

If the guess is correct on the first go, I want the statement to say "congrats it took you 1 try"; If the guess is correct on the third go, I want the statement to say "congrats it took you 3 tries".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int guess = 0;
            string welcome = "Guess a number between 1 and 10";
            int num = rand.Next(1, 10);
            int guessCount = 0;
            int guessLimit = 3;
            bool outOfGuesses = false;
            Console.WriteLine(welcome);


            int i = 0;

            while (guess != num && guessCount < guessLimit)
                
            {
                try
                {
                    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (guess > num)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Too High");
                        guessCount++;
                    }
                    if (guess < num)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Too Low");
                        guessCount++;
                    }
                }

                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess must be a number");
                    i--;
                }


                i++;
            }
            if (guess == num && guessCount != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats, it took you " + i + " tries");
            }
            if (guess == num && guessCount == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats, it took you " + i + " try");
            }
            if (guess != num && !outOfGuesses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GAME OVER, you have lost");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To improve your question, you should clarify how it is failing.

Comment: Apart from this control flow issue with `i` and the conditional checks, this code has 2 other issues.  the usage of a while loop vs do-while loop (control flow), and `outOfGuesses` logic handling.  I don't think the former will result in functional problems, but the later does.

Comment: Not sure I'm following @BrettCaswell. Shouldn't the outOfGuesses be addressed? Otherwise, I'm simply waiting for the guessLimit to be reached?

Comment: It's relevant to your code sample (and probably your overall efforts); and in that respect, it should be addressed.  But, it is out of context to how you posed this question and the problem you're facing.  That is, you indicated this question to be in regards to the failing of the logic around correct answers - which is a good scope for a question. (whereas a bad, broad scope for a question on SO is, 'what is wrong with my code')

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clarifying. 
I should have stated why it was failing, rather than getting optimisations on the other parts of the code. 

I should have also stated it fails because if the logic is met (3 or less guesses) to get the correct number, it will still write the same line "Congrats, it took you " + i + " tries". Whereas it should be writing congrats, it took you " + i + " try if it's on the first guess.

Comment: it's cool, I made a few mistakes here on the work problem logic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Increment `guessCount` just after you read input. Otherwise it will stay `0` after the correct guess from first try.

```
guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
guessCount++;
```

Also you can re-organize your conditional logic

```
if (guess == num) // all successfull results go here
{
    if (guessCount == 1) // show constant message when its 1st try
    {           
       Console.WriteLine("Congrats, it took you 1 try");
    }
    else // Use string interpolation $ to show number of tries
    {           
       Console.WriteLine($"Congrats, it took you {guessCount} tries");
    }       
}
else // you can get here only when player is out of guesses
{
    Console.WriteLine("GAME OVER, you have lost");
}
```

Variables `i` and `outOfGuesses` should be removed.

Comment: well.. this answer doesn't actually address what is\was failing in a comprehensive manner. Which is 'probably' that `i` (which is used in the console write literals) was being incremented before the condition check on guesses.

Comment: that is, demonstrating a better coding with a refactor is fine, but all the OP needed to do to was understand the control flow was a problem to his failing. (an alternative here is to move all the code following the try-catch into the try block (except for i++)).

Answer (score 0):

Although algorithm to build this game could have been better, since you are new I do not want to make things complicated for you by making too many changes. Modified code to follow your algorithm so that it is easy for you to understand. Made some changes to last three if conditions in terms of ordering of condition checking and condition itself. It seems to be working. Please refer to code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int guess = 0;
            string welcome = "Guess a number between 1 and 10";
            int num = rand.Next(1, 10);
            int guessCount = 0;
            int guessLimit = 3;
            bool outOfGuesses = false;
            Console.WriteLine(welcome);   


            int i = 0;

            while (guess != num && guessCount < guessLimit)
            {
                try
                {
                    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (guess > num)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Too High");
                        guessCount++;
                    }
                    if (guess < num)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Too Low");
                        guessCount++;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess must be a number");
                    i--;
                }

                i++;
            }

            if (guess != num && guessCount == guessLimit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GAME OVER, you have lost");
            }
            if (guess == num && guessCount == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats, it took you " + i + " try");
            }
            if (guess == num && guessCount > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats, it took you " + i + " tries");
            }           

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nccsbim071!
This does make sense, and I can see the bool statement isn't needed either to get the same result.

Comment: hmm... First, I'll leave the same comment\remark I left for Sergey's answer.  Your answer does not address what the failing is in a comprehensive manner - you're just doing the work problem.  But also, Your changes are incorrect and do not handle what was failing.  You actually made changes that cause additional logic errors. i.e. guessCount will be `== 1` or `> 1` not `0`

Comment: @BrettCaswell, question asker is new to this, too much explaining may be difficult for him to understand which is why I have answered in the pattern that he is following so that it is easy for him to grasp. Beside guessCount will be = 0 if user gets the number in first try.

Comment: ah.. my mistake.. you're right.. `guessCount++` seems to only occur when the guess is wrong... Ironically, I got caught up in the lack of information on what was failing and how these answers weren't addressing that concept that I failed to actually realize the logic and solutions of the work problem here.